# How to resolve "The argument type 'Map<String, dynamic>?' can't be assigned " on flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I tried to fetch data from doc Id but then  shows this error
"The argument type 'Map<String, dynamic>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'."
And in this code I tried to fetch from cloud firestore

image
[image]

code

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../articlesModel.dart';

class ViewOneArticleScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ViewOneArticleScreen({Key? key, required this.id}) : super(key: key);
  final String id;

  @override
  State<ViewOneArticleScreen> createState() => _ViewOneArticleScreenState();
}

class _ViewOneArticleScreenState extends State<ViewOneArticleScreen> {
  Articles? oneArticle;
  bool loading = false;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    loading = true;
    getArticle();
  }

  Future<void> getArticle() async {
    final id = widget.id;
    final reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc('articles/$id');
    final snapshot = reference.get();
    final result =
        await snapshot.then((snap) => Articles.fromJson(snap.data()));
    print('result is ====> $result');
    setState(() {
      oneArticle = result;
      loading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // print(widget.id);
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Image.network(
            oneArticle!.url,
            height: 30,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          Text(oneArticle!.topic,
              style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.black54,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
          Text(oneArticle!.description,
              style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.black54,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

To fetch I used model class. How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that `snap.data()` can be `null` (it is of type `Map<String, dynamic>?`) while doesn't support `null` (its parameter is of type `Map<String, dynamic>`).

You have 3 solutions:

### 1. You know that `snap.data()` is not `null`

Then you can use the `!` operator:

```dart
final result = await snapshot.then((snap) => Articles.fromJson(snap.data()!));
```

### 2. `Articles.fromJson` actually supports `null`

Then you can change the parameter type of `Articles.fromJson` from `Map<String, dynamic>?` to `Map<String, dynamic>`.

### 3. `Articles.fromJson` doesn't support `null` and `snap.data()` can be `null`

Then you have to support `null` yourself in your code:

```dart
final result = await snapshot.then((snap) => snap.data() == null ? null : Articles.fromJson(snap.data()!));
```

---

You can read more [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety).